# How to change font size of the first option tag in a dropdown menu (select)?

Tags: html, css, select, font-size

How can I change the font size for the first **option** tag in a **select** tag? I've tried changing the CSS for the option:first-child with no luck.

I would like the first option to have 25px font-size while the other items on the list to have 12px font-size.

I've already read tutorials here that can change the font color and font type for the first option, but when I applied font-size on them, it doesn't seem to take effect.

Can this be achieved through CSS or JQuery? Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<select>
<option>Select (25px)</option>
<option>List 1 (12px)</option>
<option>List 2 (12px)</option>
<option>List 3 (12px)</option>
<option>List 4 (12px)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Are you asking for this answer http://jsfiddle.net/D58Rz/

Comment: @airi edited with the HTML code.

Comment: @ShibinRagh all options have the same font size in Chrome

Comment: Maybe there's something in Chrome's shadow DOM, but select appearance is renderer defined and nonstandard. In Mobile Safari it uses native UI with no style or markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this below is the option you want to change the font size in SELECT tag

```
    <option id="op1">option 1</option>
```

Place the below code in head element

```
   <script>
     document.getElementById("op1").style.fontSize ="25px";
   </script>
```

Comment: hi, i tried this but it's inheriting 12px even if i add the jquery in the head.

Comment: `<optgroup style="font-size:10px">`
 `<option>Option 1</option>`
 `</optgroup>`

Comment: Yes it did. is this cross-browser? I hope it is! Thanks for the miracle and creativity!

Comment: it should be opera 9.2+ and above

Answer (score 4):

**CSS**

```
 <style>


 select{
          width: 150px;
          height: 30px;
          padding: 5px;
         font-size:12px;
        }
        select option { color: black; }
        select option:first-child
        {
          color: green;
          font-size:25px;
        }
        </style>
```

**HTML**

```
  <select>
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
    <option>item3</option>
    <option>item4</option>
    <option>item5</option>
    </select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Etr4F/839/)

Comment: in the demo, only the color changed for the first option, not the size. all option font sizes are the same in Chrome.

Comment: Same experience as @hello - colors differ but font-size all the same

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this live demo.. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amilai/Etr4F/838/).

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        Select
        <ul>
            <li><a id="first" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
  div { 
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px; 
        border: 2px solid purple; 
        width: 200px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #first{
        font-size:25px;

    }
    div > ul { display: none; }
    div:hover > ul {display: block; background: #f9f9f9; border-top: 1px solid purple;}
    div:hover > ul > li { padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #4f4f4f;}
    div:hover > ul > li:hover { background: white;}
    div:hover > ul > li:hover > a { color: red; }
```

Comment: hi, thanks. but im modifying an option tag in a select tag, not li in ul.

Comment: Ok..glad to help you out friend ! ;) And also you can accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using CSS first-child.

**Note:** Does not works in webkit browser. Change the structure to `ul > li`.

[Here is the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGtrv/)

```
select {
  font-size: 12px
}
select option:first-child {
  font-size: 25px
}
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome, all option fonts have the same size.

Comment: yeah! its not working in chrome. This is a known issue in webkit browser. I'll suggest you to change the structure to ul > li.

Answer (score 1):

You would add an id to the option tag like this:

```
<option id="newFont">Some option</option>
```

And then in the css:

```
option {
font-size: 12px;
}

option#newFont{
font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: tried this, not working for me. maybe you can help me via jsfiddle so i can see? thanks for the help!

Comment: You're right! I shouldn't assume. I've been looking at other threads and it appears that using the `select option[val="1"]` selector works on older browsers, but not in the newest version of Chrome (which is what I'm using). I'll keep looking for a solution!

Answer (score 1):

use css
**html**

```
<select id="yourSelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

**css**

```
 <style>
 #yourSelect > option:first-child
 {
   font-size: 25px;
 }
 </style>
```

or by jquery
**jquery**

```
jQuery("#yourSelect option:first-child").css('font-size', '25px');
```

Answer (score 1):

i will think twice to do like that because of browser limitation. Do check here :

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

Comment: that is why i am asking if there is a jquery solution, if css wont be able to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
// #target = your select box id 
// fontSize = your  font size;

$("#target option:first").css('font-size', fontSize);
```

Comment: -1 Absolutely nothing...but it's an awful solution to use jquery for something that can be achieved with css

Comment: @leo but -1 for this  justified ? its was a jquery solution

Comment: An awful solution to use jQuery? The question was asking, 'Can this be achieved through CSS or JQuery?'

Comment: @Kyo This is the question "Can this be achieved through CSS or JQuery? " And in my opinion (as I said) the answer is valid BUT I still have the right vote on the best answer, and that's exactly what I did

Comment: @Leo I wouldn't -1 on the correct solutions based on your preference. In the context of how the question is phrased, the solution can be implemented both via CSS and jQuery.

Comment: I did not say it was wrong...I said awful...because your adding unnecessary script execution to the browser, more dependencies between scripts and html (not to mention that you are calling the element by its name) and basically it looks like a hack, not a solution. What's still not clear? Why do I have to defend my right to vote something down?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').find('option').eq(0).css({font-size: '25px'});
```